# Delete Specific Character Between Quotation Marks in R

Tags: r, string, character, gsub

In my data frame, I have a column of strings. I would like to get rid of the comma between the string in double quotation marks, i. e.,
the comma between "Address" and "Unit".

I do NOT want to get rid of all commas.

**Situation at hand**

```
'Account1, "1234 Example Address, Unit A", Jupiter , FL, Palm Beach, 33477, United States'
```

**Desired**

```
' Account1, "1234 Example Address Unit A", Jupiter , FL, Palm Beach, 33477, United States '
```

Edit:

Was advised to mention the comma in the string will not always be between the words "Address" and "Unit"

Comment: Have you tried substituting ", Unit" with " Unit" using `gsub()`?

Comment: I have not...that can definitely fix my problem in the short term, but the word after the comma won't always be "Unit"

Comment: It would be helpful to edit your question to include the different possibilities of "Address" and "Unit" types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```r
sub('^(.*\".+),(.+\".*$)', '\\1\\2', str)
#> [1] "Account1, \"1234 Example Address Unit A\", Jupiter , FL, Palm Beach, 33477, United States "
```

Answer (score 3):

We may also do

```
gsub(',(?=[^"]*"(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*)', '', str1, perl = TRUE)
[1] " Account1 \"1234 Example Address Unit A\", Jupiter , FL, Palm Beach, 33477, United States "
```